# Advice needed for organising product database

Tags: sql, python-3.x, flask, database-design

I’m really new to databases so apologies in advance. I’m working on a private flask app for ordering products. I have a table of customers (with a customer ID) and a table of all the products for sale (unique product codes) which all seems straight forward. There is a third table with product variants (again, with unique codes) that are customised with the customers logo.

How could I set it up so that when they choose the product from table one, it will know to choose the alternative product from table two? I thought about setting up individual product tables per customer but I have some 300+ customers and don’t fancy writing and updating 300+ tables.

I hope this makes sense, all searches so far have only given answers for something simple like t-shirt sizes, but the complexity of the customisation means the customer will have a mix of products with their logo and without.

Any general advice or suggestions would be a huge help! Thank you.

Comment: What if a customer has more than one customization?

Comment: So they might order 30 unique products in a single order, 10 of which are only available as customised with their logo. It depends on the customer and the annual spend whether they are eligible for items with their logo on so it can go up or down.

Comment: If I understand your problem description correctly, each product has a one-to-one relationship with a customized product.  A foreign key from the product to the customized product should allow you to get the customized product from the product.

Comment: This sounds promising, how will the foreign key know to select that customers specific code? A foreign key from the customer table and one from the main product table to the alternative product table? Each customised product has its own unique code different to another customers, I’m working with poorly designed data which the company I work for aren’t able to clean up.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I think I've mostly solved the problem with thanks to the commenters. I realised I need to set up some consistent references/identifiers across my tables to connect everything up the way I need it too. Below is a very crude quick mockup to jot down the relationships in the database. Ignore the fact the datatypes are all random, if anyone has any further comments that would be great, but otherwise I think I'm slowly figuring this out.
[Basic DB Design](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XNniT.jpg)